# Remove extra space above and below large text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have large text, like this:

[image]

As you can see, when I highlight the text, Word automatically adds space above and below the text (marked in red).

How can I get rid of this extra spacing?

My line spacing is set to 1 (single line), and there is 0 spacing before and after the text.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is extra spacing. This is just like T looks in this font. If you e.g. write "g" instead of "T" the bottom space will be smaller. However you can experiment with setting Line spacing in Paragraph dialog box to "Exactly" and specifying spacing value in points to get rid of some part of this "extra spacing".

Comment: The red isn't to indicate spacing above the T specifically. No matter what you type, you end up with extra spacing above and below the text. Specifying "exactly" only removes space on the bottom, but not the top.

Comment: That's why I wrote "some part of this extra spacing". I think this behaviour is normal and font specific and happens not only for large text. Change font and see that the spacing changes for the same letter as this is how this letter was designed to look.

Comment: Most of the space below isn't extra. It is there to accommodate the part of lower case characters such as j and y that descend below the baseline. This is part of the font specification. Fonts have been created that do not have this but they look unnatural.